# Add Differing Ticker Times

Tags: scheme, racket, ticker

Hi can you help me add a way to have different timer lengths for each light. I'm doing a world state/big bang program that creates a traffic light that cycles between green, yellow and red while it goes immediately to green if you hit the Spacebar. I have everything running but I couldn't adjust the ticker to be different its always a constant time.

```
(require 2htdp/image)
(require 2htdp/universe)

;; =================
;; Constants:

(define WIDTH 600)
(define HEIGHT 350)
(define MTS (empty-scene WIDTH HEIGHT))
(define RAD 50)
(define WIDTH_2 (/ WIDTH 2))
(define CTR-Y (/ HEIGHT 2))

;; =================
;; Functions:

;; trafficLightNext Tests
(check-expect (trafficLightNext "red") "green")
(check-expect (trafficLightNext "yellow") "red")
(check-expect (trafficLightNext "green") "yellow")

;; Traffic Light -> Boolean
;; Find the current-state of a Traffic Light (red, yellow or green)
(define (isRed? current-state)
  (string=? "red" current-state))
(define (isYellow? current-state)
  (string=? "yellow" current-state))
(define (isGreen? current-state)
  (string=? "green" current-state))

;; Traffic Light -> Traffic Light
;; Finds the next state for the Traffic Light
(define (trafficLightNext current-state)
   (cond
    [(isRed? current-state) "green"]
    [(isYellow? current-state) "red"]
    [(isGreen? current-state) "yellow"]))

;; Render Tests
(check-expect (bulb "red" "red") (circle RAD "solid" "red"))
(check-expect (bulb "green" "green") (circle RAD "solid" "green"))
(check-expect (bulb "yellow" "red") (circle RAD "outline" "red"))

(define (light=? current-state color)
  (string=? current-state color))

;; Traffic Light -> Image
;; Renders the the light
(define (bulb on c)
  (if (light=? on c) (circle RAD "solid" c) (circle RAD "outline" c)))


;; Traffic Light -> Image
;; Takes a Traffic Light places the image on the scene
(define (trafficLightRender current-state)
 (place-image
   (bulb current-state "red")   
   WIDTH_2
   52
   (place-image
    (bulb current-state "yellow")
    WIDTH_2
    CTR-Y
     (place-image
      (bulb current-state "green")     
     WIDTH_2
     298
      MTS))))

;; TrafficLight -> TrafficLight
;; Traffic Light changes every second
(define (traffic-light-simulation initial-state)
  (big-bang initial-state (on-tick trafficLightNext 1) (to-draw trafficLightRender) (on-key ambulance)))

;; Key -> TrafficLight
;; Changes light to green everytime key is touched
 (define (ambulance initial-state key)
  (cond [(key=? key " ") "green"]
        (else initial-state)))

(check-expect (ambulance "yellow" " ") "green")
(check-expect (ambulance "red" " ") "green")
(check-expect (ambulance "yellow" "d") "yellow")
```

Answer (score 0):

As this looks like a school assignment, I won't give you a full solution, only leads.

It would have been easier if the `rate-expr` of the [`on-tick` clause](http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpuniverse.html?q=on-tick#%28form._world._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Funiverse..rkt%29._on-tick%29%29) of `big-bang` were a function taking the current state as input, but this is not the case, so you need a (functional) way around.

One possibility is to make your world state a bit more complicated: instead of being only the current light, it could be the light plus a countdown value. At each tick, you do not immediately change the light, but instead you decrement (subtract 1 from) the counter of the state. When the countdown hits 0, you change the light and reinitialize the countdown to a value that depends on the new light.
The main changes are in the `trafficLightNext` function and tests, but the rest of the program must also be modified, as the state is different.